# (ssg-wsg) No start line

Tags: pem

Have the following errors regarding PEM file using API with “Authentication” = “Certificate”

On Postman:

```
PEM routines:OPENSSL_internal:NO_START_LINE
```

On github node js sample:

```
node:_tls_common:155
    context.setCert(cert);
            ^

Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at setCerts (node:_tls_common:155:13)
    at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:210:7)
    at Object.connect (node:_tls_wrap:1591:48)
    at Agent.createConnection (node:https:129:22)
    at Agent.createSocket (node:_http_agent:323:26)
    at Agent.addRequest (node:_http_agent:274:10)
    at new ClientRequest (node:_http_client:314:16)
    at Object.request (node:https:313:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kthxbai/Downloads/index.js:25:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14) {
  library: 'PEM routines',
  function: 'get_name',
  reason: 'no start line',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your certificate PEM file does not have the following lines which lead to the error.

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

```
...<your cert>...
```

-----END CERTIFICATE-----